# Mongo Error E11000 get key name using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am creating an index whose having a unique index and I am trying to insert documents in that collection but using the insertMany option. I am also using Mongo Transaction also. When I am trying to insert a duplicate document in MongoDB it giving me the following index error:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: demo.unique_values index: unique_name dup key: { : "1234", : "testing", : "en-us", : "number", : 400, : false }
    
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1623229996 },
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: demo.unique_values index: unique_name dup key: { : "1234", : "testing", : "en-us", : "number", : 400, : false }',
  code: 11000,
  codeName: 'DuplicateKey',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1623229996 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: 0 }
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

it is giving me information about my unique index but I want the error key number field here so How I can get this?

Also as I am using MongoDB Transaction with insertMany query with ordered: false option but still it is showing error for a single field, not all fields which having duplicate values for e.g: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#unordered-inserts.

I need all errors of Insert Many and in a proper format. I am using Transaction.
When I am using insertMany without transaction and order false it gives me error like

```
{
    "name": "BulkWriteError",
    "driver": true,
    "code": 11000,
    "writeErrors": [{
        "code": 11000,
        "index": 0,
        "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: demo.unique_values index: unique_name dup key: { : \"1234\", : \"testing\", : \"en-us\", : \"number\", : \"400\", : false }",
        "op": {
            "key": "1234",
            "type_uid": "testing",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "path": "number",
            "value": "400",
            "deleted_at": false,
            "_id": "60c08ad651ab70014397dbab"
        }
    }, {
        "code": 11000,
        "index": 1,
        "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: demo.unique_values index: unique_name dup key: { : \"1234\", : \"testing\", : \"en-us\", : \"title\", : \"tiger\", : false }",
        "op": {
            "key": "1234",
            "content_type_uid": "testing",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "path": "title",
            "value": "tiger",
            "deleted_at": false,
            "_id": "60c08ad651ab70014397dbac"
        }
    }],
    "result": {
        "ok": 1,
        "writeErrors": [{
            "code": 11000,
            "index": 0,
            "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: demo.unique_values index: unique_name dup key: { : \"1234\", : \"testing\", : \"en-us\", : \"number\", : \"400\", : false }",
            "op": {
                "key": "1234",
                "type_uid": "testing",
                "locale": "en-us",
                "path": "number",
                "value": "400",
                "deleted_at": false,
                "_id": "60c08ad651ab70014397dbab"
            }
        }, {
            "code": 11000,
            "index": 1,
            "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: demo.unique_values index: unique_name dup key: { : \"1234\", : \"testing\", : \"en-us\", : \"title\", : \"tiger\", : false}",
            "op": {
                "key": "1234",
                "ype_uid": "testing",
                "locale": "en-us",
                "path": "title",
                "value": "tiger",
                "deleted_at": false,
                "_id": "60c08ad651ab70014397dbac"
            }
        }],
        "writeConcernErrors": [],
        "insertedIds": [{
            "index": 0,
            "_id": "60c08ad651ab70014397dbab"
        }, {
            "index": 1,
            "_id": "60c08ad651ab70014397dbac"
        }],
        "nInserted": 0,
        "nUpserted": 0,
        "nMatched": 0,
        "nModified": 0,
        "nRemoved": 0,
        "upserted": [],
        "lastOp": {
            "ts": "6971724857717293057",
            "t": 606
        }
    }
 }
```

it showing all failed fields details so How I get this using Transaction

Code sample

```
try{
let session = await adaptor.startSession({});
await session.withTransaction(async () => {
    await adaptor.updateMany("unique_values",
                    {
                        key:{{key}},
                        uid:{{uid}},
                        locale:{{locale}},
                        type_uid:{{type_uid}},
                        deleted_at:false
                    }, {
                        $set:{
                        deleted_at:true
                    }},{session})
                    await adaptor.insertMany("unique_values",[{
```

"key":"1234",
"type_uid": "testing",
"locale": "en-us",
"path": "number",
"value": "400",
"deleted_at": false,
}],
{

```
                        ordered: false
                    },
                    
                    );
                    await adaptor.deleteMany("unique_values",{
                        key:{{key}},
                        uid:{{uid}},
                        locale:{{locale}},
                        type_uid:{{type_uid}},
                        deleted_at:false
                    },{session})
})
}catch(error){
    
}
```

Kindly help me!

Answer (score 1):

This is from Mongo Documenation:

> Excluding Write Concern errors, ordered operations stop after an
> error, while unordered operations continue to process any remaining
> write operations in the queue.
>
> Write concern errors are displayed in the writeConcernErrors field,
> while all other errors are displayed in the writeErrors field. If an
> error is encountered, the number of successful write operations are
> displayed instead of a list of inserted _ids. Ordered operations
> display the single error encountered while unordered operations
> display each error in an array.

You can see in the documentation that in unordered ops the mongo drive keeps the updating the other operations and respond with `write Concern` what is causing an issue. In your case `_id: 1234` is duplicate.

Try to add writeConcerns and you will be able to see all the duplicate Ids in a form of an array. Check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#unordered-inserts) link.

Comment: how we can write Concern in insert many for transaction?

Comment: if possible can you please share one example of this

Comment: The issue is with the data you are trying to write if you can add that I will add one. It seems from the error stack the id which i mentioned is coming twice.

Comment: Updated the question can you please check it ? and help me

Comment: kindly help mere here to add write Concern in 
let session = await adaptor.startSession({});

Comment: Buddy, you are already getting it. What you have updated is the same thing and you can see multiple objects which states that `id` is being duplicated many times.  So, theses documents are having same ID which you need to change so that it can update all the data in one go.

Comment: sorry but I am not getting it.

Comment: when I use insertMany without session iand when i check query it showing "writeConcern" : { "w" : 1 } but with session insertMany query not showing writeConcern. because of this I getting different error message

Comment: When the query fails it gives you the write errors which is being given. `"key": "1234", "type_uid": "testing","locale": "en-us", "path": "number","value": "400",
 "deleted_at": false, "_id": "60c08ad651ab70014397dbab"` and `"key": "1234", "content_type_uid": "testing","locale": "en-us", "path": "title", "value": "tiger","deleted_at": false, "_id": "60c08ad651ab70014397dbac"` . These two have same `key` and this is the problem you are getting this error.

Comment: yes the key is the same but when I use insertMany without session and when i check query it showing "writeConcern" : { "w" : 1 } with valid result but with session insertMany query not showing writeConcern. because of this I getting different error message

Comment: It is because with session you might be adding some new data which is hard for me to debug.

Comment: also what about order: false in InseertMany. please check the error with the session and without the session. I am doing the same thing in without session also but error message showing writeErrors options but with session, it showing different format

Comment: new Data not getting how we can pass writeConcern in session

Comment: pleas help me here

Comment: Try saving two data with different IDs and with session, it should work.

Comment: sorry but i am not saving _id any where

Comment: can you share some more code of sessions and transactions in the question? Or Share the code ?

Comment: added code snippet please check and help me

Comment: is the code sample help to understand this?

Comment: is anything related to this kindly let me know

Comment: kindly check:https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-38583 it also related to the error message in the session.